# Universal argument emacs (C-u) and minus sign

Tags: emacs

One of my basic usage for `C-u` under emacs is to **quickly** generate separator comments.

For instance `C-u C-u C-u =` generates 64 chars `=`

```
================================================================
```

`C-u C-u /` generates 16 chars `/` and so on....

```
////////////////
```

**My problem is that it does not work with the minus sign `-`**.

When typing `C-u C-u C-u -` Emacs waits for some digits (to form a negative number) and does not print the line of 64 `-` char.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

**My question:** is there a workaround, some kind of trick to 'escape' the minus sign when using the `C-u` command?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `quoted-insert` to prevent the `-` being captured:

<kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

Or enter the number manually:

- <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>4</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>
- <kbd>M-6</kbd><kbd>M-4</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, I learned new stuff! Both solutions work perfectly and I did not know the `quoted-insert` function.

Comment: `quoted-insert` is a good thing to keep in mind in general, as there are a variety of situations where keybindings can prevent you from inserting particular characters (e.g. SPC is commonly captured in minibuffer input, and `C-q C-j` may be necessary for entering a newline). Having a standard way to circumvent these kinds of issue is useful.